# how to extract or get bits out of two byte array in c# and store it in separate variable for each bit extracted?

Tags: arrays, bitwise-operators, bit

I have a two-byte array like this:

```
byte[] buffer;
```

creating a byte[] called buffer

```
buffer[2];
```

buffer of 2 byte

now i want to extract each bit from 2 byte, like 0 to 15 data bits, so thati can store them in a seperate variable.

Till now i have done this.

```
var extractbits= buffer[2];
Bitarray extractedBits_ = new bitarray(extractbits);                                     
var bit_0 = extractedBits_ [0];                     
var bit_1=extractedBits_ [1];
```

so on ...
but i failed to get the info..it shows all false in bool, even though there was value in them byte.

value in the buffer[2] is 255;
is there any other way to do this

Comment: 1) C and C# are **very different** languages. Use the correct language tag and don't spam tags! 2) See [ask], provide a [mcve] 3) and state your **specific** problem. This problem has been asked and answered multiple times already. If not as a ready-made solution, then the required steps.

Comment: Half of this code isn't even valid c#.  Please show the actual code you compiled and tested - we can't debug broken pieces of fake code.

Comment: you guys are rude to a first timer

Answer (score 0):

You can initialise your extractedBits_ with the proper constructor like this:

```
        byte[] arr = new byte[2];
        arr[0] = 255;
        arr[1] = 255;

        var extractedBits_= new BitArray(arr);
        var length = arr.Length * 8;
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(extractedBits_[i]);
        }
        //True
        //True
        //True
        //True
        //True
        //True
        //True
        //False
        //True
        //True
        //True
        //True
        //True
        //True
        //True
        //True
```